# Checkboxes in dropdown with geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

I'm a newbie here
I'm using this dropdown which lists all countries with help of chosen-rails and country-select gem.

```
<%= country_select :country, ['United States of America'], { include_blank: true }, { class: 'chosen-select' } %>
```

I want to do is have checkboxes in front of every country listed in dropdown with multiple selection and also I want to do something like this site is using.

https://www.cofounderslab.com/

A search box in dropdown so that user can search through countries and also a functionality that after selecting his/her country he can search through area within 100miles or 50 miles .. . for this i come up with geocoder gem but unable to make it
already wasted 2 days for this 
any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your question could stand some improvement.  Do you think you could tighten it up to make it more clear what question you are asking?  For example, instead of just linking to another site and asking us to go look, show a focused screen shot showing the effect you want to achieve.  Also please add any code you've tried.

Comment: imgur.com/qwzU2t6
In this you can see the dropdown has option for checkboxes and in that dropdown i want to fetch values from 3 different models

imgur.com/rB4WeAE
In this image as you can clearly understand when we select a city with how many miles then according to that it will display the data. and for this i have come up with Geocoder gem but completely blank on how to use that.

Answer (score 1):

I you hafe to iterate ofer the list with countries and make a checkbox for each of them

```
<% @country.each do |country| %>
   // here you have to do your checkboxes 
 <%end%>
```

Comment: I did this<% @country.each do |country| %>
   <%= country_select :country,{ class: 'chosen-select' } %>
 <%end%>
but i got :- undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass 
this is all i have in my index 
<%= country_select :country,{ class: 'chosen-select' } %>
and as i understand from your answer it won't do coz i am listing countries in dropdown via chose-rails and country select gem